# SPS2010 Server Farm installation without DC/AD

Tags: server-farm

My HOST PC is Windows 7 and using VirtualBox I have setup a Virtual Machine having:

- Windows 2008 Server R2 Enterprise (Standalone - there is no AD/DC)
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Express
- SharePoint 2010 Server Enterprise Trial

Now, I want to install SPS 2010 and make use of the existing SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.  During the Installation, I selected **Server Farm** and then **Complete** option.  So far, so good.

Next, it started PSConfig Wizard and asked me to specify the DB details.  I provided the local Server Name and gave a New DB name.  Now, it throws error saying that it needs a User ID in Domain\UserID format.  I tried giving my LocalServerName\UserID, but it doesn't accept.  I even tried "sa" User ID, but that too didn't work.

**Questions:**
1) I don't have AD/DC in this setup.  Can I setup a Farm in such environment?
2) The StandAlone option creates its own SQL Server Express Instance.  I want to avoid this and reuse the "already" installed SQL Server 208 R2 Express.

Are the above tasks "Mission Impossible"? or is there any alternative to do such a setup? This task is purely for learning purpose and not for a Production use.

Answer (score 1):

Running SharePoint 2010 using local accounts. Check out the following articles:

- [Single Server Complete Install of SharePoint 2010 using local accounts](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/fromthefield/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=112)
- [Tips for building SharePoint 2010 base VM images](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/05/tips-for-building-sharepoint-2010-base.html)

More [on Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=installing+sharepoint+2010+using+local+accounts).